# How to extract parts of string using R and place them in different columns

Tags: r, regex, split

I do have a column of text from which I want to extract pieces of information and place them in a new columns.

Example:

```
Text-1 <- "issue : there has been considerable changes and it is going on. finding : we need further investigation on this. resolution: please check the validity"

Text-2 <- "issue : there has been considerable changes and it is going on. resolution: please check the validity"

Text-3 <- "finding : we need further investigation on this. resolution: please check the validity"

Text-4 <- "please check the validity"
```

The solution that I am looking for is when we apply the R regular expression the intended result should be like below. The text is split into 3 different columns based on its presence.

### Text-1

```
issue <- there has been considerable changes and it is going on 

finding <- we need further investigation on this

resolution <- please check the validity
```

### Text-2

```
issue <- there has been considerable changes and it is going on

finding <- NA

resolution <- please check the validity
```

### Text-3

```
issue <- NA

finding <- we need further investigation on this

resolution <- please check the validity
```

### Text-4

```
issue <- NA

finding <- NA

resolution <- please check the validity
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package *unglue* :

```r
library(unglue)
text <- c(
  "issue : there has been considerable changes and it is going on. finding : we need further investigation on this. resolution: please check the validity",
  "issue : there has been considerable changes and it is going on. resolution: please check the validity",
  "finding : we need further investigation on this. resolution: please check the validity",
  "please check the validity")

patterns <- c("issue : {issue}. finding : {finding}. resolution: {resolution}",
              "issue : {issue}. resolution: {resolution}",
              "finding : {finding}. resolution: {resolution}")

unglue_data(text, patterns)
#>                                                    issue
#> 1 there has been considerable changes and it is going on
#> 2 there has been considerable changes and it is going on
#> 3                                                   <NA>
#> 4                                                   <NA>
#>                                 finding                resolution
#> 1 we need further investigation on this please check the validity
#> 2                                  <NA> please check the validity
#> 3 we need further investigation on this please check the validity
#> 4                                  <NA>                      <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It won't be of much help if your real case has a lot more combinations than this example, but in this case it works ok, we give the 3 possible patterns in a vector and the first working pattern is used, the results are given in a data frame with one column for each extracted variable.

To start from a data frame and add columns, use `unglue_unnest(your_df, your_col, patterns)` and set `remove = FALSE` if you want to keep the original column.